# Socket.io page refresh

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets

I am making a one to one chat application using socket.io and mongodb, whenever I refresh the page a new socket connection is formed, whenever user joins the chat he needs to refresh the page at the beginning then only it starts receiving messages. Can anyone tell me how to avoid it?

I am using express-session to store the session.

```
  var sessionInit = session({
  name: 'userCookie',
  secret: '9743-980-270-india',
  resave: true,
  httpOnly: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: new mongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection
  }),
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 80 * 80 * 800
  }
});

app.use(sessionInit);
```

Comment: use socket authentication which enable user to connect only one socket thought out app

Answer (score -2):

Maybe not the best thing to do but you can use

```
window.location.reload();
```

when someone joins the chat so they don't have to do it by themselves